# How to get products from order, order entries, and orders status from query

Tags: mysql, sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I prepared a flexible search query. Here, I developed a condition like:

1. Order status is completed in orders
2. And order entries which are present in order
3. Getting products which are in orderentries

For this I wrote a query

```
select {p.pk} from {
  order as o 
  join OrderStatus as os on {os.pk}={o.status}
  join orderentry as oe on{oe.order}={o.pk}
  join product as p on {oe.product}={p.pk}
}
where {os.code}='COMPLETED' 
AND {o.date}>'2020-08-16 00:00:00.000' AND{o.date}<'2020-09-30 00:00:00.000' 
group by{p.pk} order by count({oe.pk}) desc limit 10
```

here in this query what I want is I want to get all product information like

```
select * from Product}
```

How to modify this query get all products?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a subselect. The first query you posted above will be the subselect. You simply need to add another select to fetch the product information for all the PKs returned in the subselect.

```sql
select * from {Product as prod} where {prod.pk} in 
({{ 
  select 
    top 10 {p.pk} 
  from 
    {
      Order as o join 
      OrderStatus as os on {os.pk} = {o.status} join 
      OrderEntry as oe on {oe.order} = {o.pk} join 
      Product as p on {oe.product} = {p.pk}
    }
  where 
    {os.code} = 'COMPLETED' and 
    {o.date} > '2020-08-16 00:00:00.000' and 
    {o.date} < '2020-09-30 00:00:00.000'
  group by {p.pk} 
  order by count({oe.pk}) desc
}})
```

Comment: that was great thank you.  but i am also adding the limit , wich was i am taking from another table can i include it it heare like .select {numberOfProducts} from {topsellingproductcomponent}. it returns the number(like 10).so i can limit the values wich are comming

Comment: See my edited query above. Just needed a slight modification. Should do the trick

Comment: Also, I don't think there's any way to do what you're asking with the {topsellingproductcomponent} value in the select statement. A groovy script would probably be the best way of achieving that.